# setpgrp causes tty gone

Tags: process, tty, process-groups

When using `setpgrp` `vi` (and other tty programs) work completely different than if `setpgrp` is not used. Example:

```
perl -MIPC::Open3 -e '$pid= open3("<&STDIN", ">&STDOUT", ">&STDERR", qw(perl -e),q(exec qw(bash -c),qq(vi foo))); wait'
```

That works great and calls `vi foo`. But add `setpgrp`:

```
perl -MIPC::Open3 -e '$pid= open3("<&STDIN", ">&STDOUT", ">&STDERR", qw(perl -e),q(setpgrp;exec qw(bash -c),qq(vi foo))); wait'
```

and then it does not work so well.

Tested on GNU/Linux (Mint), FreeBSD, OpenBSD, Solaris, HPUX, AIX, Dragonfly. All give similar behaviour.

Why? Can I somehow create a process group and still spawn tty tools like `vi`?

**Background**

The above is part of a possible extension of GNU Parallel that will allow to kill the process groups instead of processes, and is thus a tiny corner of the full program. An answer to just run `vi foo` is thus not a useful answer.

Comment: Making a process a session leader detaches it from the current terminal, yes.  I strongly recommend you R. Stevens' book [Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment](http://www.apuebook.com/).

Comment: Neat project, but I think `pkill -g` already covers this.

Comment: @lcd047 I can't be sure, it's been 20+ years, but the edition of Stevens' that I read didn't cover process groups because they had yet to be invented at the time of his writing.

Comment: @Otheus: Ah, that brings back memories. :) I have the first edition here, from 1993, and section 9.4 (p. 243) is named "Process Groups".  Looking at the TOC, almost everything there is still relevant today, the only exceptions being the chapter about modems, and to some extent the references to STREAMS.  Which I suppose pretty much reflects the state of UNIX today.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for invalidating my memory :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `setpgrp` man page from Darwin/MacOS (BSD-based):

> If the calling process is not already a session leader, setpgrp() sets
>   the process group ID of the calling process to that of the calling
>   process.  **Any new session that this creates will have no controlling
>   terminal.**

There's your answer.